# How can I make a a subdirectory in my GitHub project into a new repository?

Tags: git, github, git-filter-branch

I recently moved a couple of subdirectories in a project of mine on GitHub, and I was curious about the best way to clone a subdirectory into a new project. Specifically, I want any mentions of issues in the commit messages for these new projects to point to the old project.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detach subdirectory into separate Git repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359424/detach-subdirectory-into-separate-git-repository)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Despite [hype around new commands like `git subtree split`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359424/detach-subdirectory-into-separate-git-repository/17864475#17864475), the best way to make a new Git project from a subdirectory of an old Git project is still to clone the project, then use [`git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch#_examples) to rewrite the project's history to only include the given subdirectory.

However, with GitHub, there's still a little more work to do- if you're taking commits from an old project into a new repository, you may have references in your commit messages to issues from that original repository (such as `Fixes #3`). If you're going to re-use these commits in another project, you'll need to convert them to *explicit* references to issues in the original repository (such as `Fixes stuartpb/mothership#3`), so that the "new" commits in the separated project will be linked to that original issue, and *won't* get linked to any of the *new* project's issues.

Luckily, `git filter-branch` provides an option to filter commit messages as well, so we can do all this in just a few commands:

- $WORK_DIR refers to the directory you want to check your project out to.
- $SUB_DIR is the subdirectory you want to convert to a separate project.
- $ORIGINAL_REPO is the username-and-repo-name of the project with the subdirectory you're splitting.
- $NEW_REPO is the username-and-repo-name you want to push the *new* repo to.

The commands, from start to finish:

```
git clone https://github.com/$ORIGINAL_REPO $WORK_DIR && cd $WORK_DIR
git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter $SUB_DIR --msg-filter 'sed -re
  "s=(^| )(#[0-9]+)=\1'$ORIGINAL_REPO'#\2"=g' -- --all
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:$NEW_REPO.git
git push -u origin master
```

Comment: Why add a new question/answer instead of just adding your answer to [an existing question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/359424/617937)?

Comment: Because my question/answer is GitHub-specific. Other questions are only about doing this for Git repositories in general.

Comment: What people fail to understand is that Github '''is''' Git. The commands above are just how to do it from the console.

Comment: Uh, "Git" doesn't have an issue tracker, which is what half the content of this answer pertains to addressing.